# Can it posible to save aggregate function setting of Telerik in database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik-grid

My client want to save aggregate function that applyed on radgrid columns.

This [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grdsavingsettingsonperuserbasis.html) is helpful i do this thing but no help for saving aggregate functions.

Check this link first and if it possible to save aggregate functions then please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply aggregate function by query **like item.sum(salary) group by salary** 
saved it into database and when you rebind Radgrid by group expression its automatically bind